# ESP-01 not waking correctly up after deep sleep

Tags: esp8266, ds18b20, mqtt

I have an ESP-01 that I want to measure pool temperature with. It will send the data over MQTT to the broker.

I have connected RST to GPIO16 so I can use the deep sleep functionality. Currently I am testing sending a "hello world" to the MQTT broker, and everything works fine when booting up the first time, but it seems like the ESP never wakes up correctly after the first deep sleep.

My script looks like this:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Set ADC mode
ADC_MODE(ADC_VCC);

// WiFi settings
const char* ssid = "Network";
const char* password = "Password";
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 100);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

// MQTT settings
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.110";
const int mqtt_port = 1883;
const char* mqtt_user = "User";
const char* mqtt_pass = "Password";
const char* mqtt_client_name = "poolsensor";
const char* mqtt_topic = "pool";

// Data wire plugged into D1 on the ESP8266 ESP-01 - GPIO 5
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 5

// Setup OneWire instance to communicate with any device
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our OneWire reference to Dallas Temperature
DallasTemperature DS18B20(&oneWire);

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup_wifi() {
  delay(10);

  // Annuonce connection
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  // Setup WiFi config and connect
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're connected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");

    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(mqtt_client_name, mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)) {
      // Success
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      // Fail
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");

      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Start WiFi setup
  setup_wifi();

  // Set MQTT server
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, mqtt_port);

  // Set resolution to 0.25
  DS18B20.setResolution(10);

  // Start sensor
  DS18B20.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  } else {
    // Get temperature
    /*
    DS18B20.requestTemperatures();
    float temp = DS18B20.getTempCByIndex(0);

    if ((temp > -20) && (temp < 60)) {
      client.publish("pool/temperature", String(temp).c_str(), true);
    }
    */

    client.publish("pool/temperature", "hello world");
    Serial.println("published temperature");

    delay(1000);

    // Sleep
    ESP.deepSleep(60 * 1000000);

    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Everything looks good in the serial monitor when compiling and uploading code, as the code runs the first time:

```cpp
Connecting to Network
......
Connected, IP address: 192.168.0.100
Attempting MQTT connection...connected
published temperature
```

And I can see in my MQTT debugger that it receives `hello world`. After around 60 seconds, the following is shown in the serial monitor (lots of gibberish):

```cpp
{l�l��|��d�|�d�b<����s�c$�#��ng�lgn���cxp��${$sd�s��'�c�ncp��
```

This is the last message I ever receive from the ESP, so I assume it never deep sleeps again and runs over the code again.

Anyone experienced the same, or see a bug in my code?

Comment: you have io 0 LOW?

Comment: How did you connect anything to GPIO16 on an ESP01? Other than very carefully of course - and `D1`??? that's wemos/nodemcu garbage (plus the  ESP01 doesn't break out gpio 5 either

Comment: if you set your serial monitor to 74880 baud, then you may be able to read the gibberish

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually the temp. sensor is not connected yet, so I commented out the code. I ran a thin copper wire from RST to the correct pin on the chip. Baud 74880 worked, and it reads the following: `ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:5, boot mode:(1,6) ets_main.c` but only once, and never more.  @Juraj no, should I use `pinMode(0, LOW);` ?

Comment: `boot mode:(1,6)` look that up , I think you're in "Download code from UART" mode - `should I use pinMode(0, LOW);` no, or yes, doesn't make a difference

Comment: `boot mode:(1,6)` definitely "Download code from UART" mode - you need to make sure GPIO0 (and GPIO2 - but that doesn't seem so flakey on an ESP01) are HIGH on boot - use a pullup resistor from GPIO0 to VCC

Comment: @dandavis, he answered that " I ran a thin copper wire from RST to the correct pin on the chip"

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a similar issue - receive a lot of gibberish after coming back. Changing Baud to 74880 revealed `boot mode:(3,7)`. Does this mean that GPIO0 and GPIO2 are high as they should, but something else is wrong? DFRobot show in their diagram that XPD is connected, which is shortcurcuited to RESET.

Comment: @JensMunk `boot mode:(3,?)` does indeed mean the 0 and 2 are high and 15 (MTDO) is low, as it should be for "normal" boot - so that's not your problem

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you will need gpio 16 connected to reset in order for this to ever work, it’s tricky but not impossible. Have a read here:

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-deep-sleep-with-arduino-ide/

Comment: I did that. Small copper wire from RST to GPIO16 on the chip.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. From your code above it should be waking as expected. As others have said pulling GPIO 0 high is required for normal boot, GPIO 2 is not required but it is good practice to ensure stability. What you are most likely seeing and what I have seen in the past, if you have GPIO 0 grounded, i.e. to program with the arduino IDE, immediately after programming is complete, the chip will reboot normally and run with GPIO 0 grounded, but only once. If you leave GPIO 0 grounded and reboot again (or the chip wakes from sleep) it will not boot. Take GPIO 0 high and it should  work.

Answer (score 1):

You left io 0 floating. With io 0 not HIGH at boot, the esp8266 goes into flashing mode.

The wake-up from deep-sleep is boot startup. So your code doesn't start if io 0 is not pulled high. Add a pull-up for io 0.

If you set Serial Monitor to 74880 baud, you will see the boot-log readable. It will print 1 as first value in "boot mode". This value is set from state of io 15, 2 and 0. 15 should be LOW and io 2 and io 0 HIGH for normal boot. `1` indicates that only 2 is HIGH.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not quite sure if I understand. No guides I've read says I have to pull 0 high. I use a programmer for programming, but I still have the same initial issue when I disconnect the programmer and just connect VCC and GND to a power source.

Comment: every good esp-01 tutorial connects EN and io 0 to VCC. I would use a pull-up resistor

Comment: do you understand that io 0 state at boot determines if the board boots to application or to bootloader?

Comment: Of course, but previously I never have to do this. I've used ESP-01 in several projects, but never with deep sleep, so this is new to me.

Comment: after upload it start without reboot

Comment: fwiw, i've found you need to wire EN to VCC on the ESP-01. but not on the ESP-01S, if that clarifies things.

Comment: yes, 01S has pull-ups on board, but then to flash it io 0 most be connected to ground

Comment: Ok, maybe I actually have an 01 and not 01S. I will do some research on this.

Comment: @Ronny-AndréBendiksen, what is the result? did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i found out, my CH_PD pin and RST pin were shorted together, when i was connecting wire from RST to GPIO_16. On the chip, the CH_PD pin is next to GPIO_16, so when you short them, the RST pin is always high, so esp cannot reboot anymore without external grounding. I fixed it and now deep sleep is working again!