# ESP8266 remapping or UART boot

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to make an DFRobot Wifi Bee sleep periodically. The first run executes fine, but after the wakeup a lot of gibberish is shown in the serial monitor. I changed to baud rate to 74880 to see what was going on.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(74880);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);
  while (!Serial) { }
  Serial.println("Started.");
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Going to sleep.");
  delay(10);
  ESP.deepSleep(10e6);
}
void loop() { }
```

If I short-circuit D0 and RST, I get the following output

```
18:28:25.250 -> Going to sleep.
18:28:54.197 -> 
18:28:54.197 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:5, boot mode:(3,7)
18:28:54.197 -> 
18:28:54.197 -> ets_main.c
```

Indicating that both GPIO0 and GPIO2 are high (which they should) and the cause of reset is power on and hardware watchdog reset.

A similar question has already been asked and answered [ESP-01 not waking correctly up after deep sleep](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61770/esp-01-not-waking-correctly-up-after-deep-sleep), but my issue is different, since I get the correct first boot parameter = 3 (both GPIO0 and GPIO2 are high)

I read here https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8386#sthash.82ae9lvh.dpuf that the second boot parameter means

```
7 SDIO HighSpeed V2 IO  Uart1 Booting
6 SDIO LowSpeed V1 IO   Uart1 Booting
5 SDIO HighSpeed V1 IO  Uart1 Booting
4 SDIO LowSpeed V2 IO   Uart1 Booting
3 FLASH BOOT    
2 Jump Boot 
1 UART Boot 
0 Remapping
```

I believe that I must change something to receive `boot mode:(3,3). If I remove the wire from GPIO16 to RST, I get almost the same result

```
18:41:25.250 -> Going to sleep.
18:41:54.197 -> 
18:41:54.197 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:5, boot mode:(3,0)
18:41:54.197 -> 
18:41:54.197 -> ets_main.c
```

So now a Remapping occurs (or?).

I am running the module using an FDTI USB connector from SparkFun.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you wire io 16 to rst on this board?

Comment: They has a link showing that the XPD signal (GPIO16) and RST were connected to physical PIN 9 and 12. Just added a jumper wire.

Comment: The schematic link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arduinolibrary/DFRobot_Wifi_Bee_ESP8266/master/TEL0092%20Wifi%20Bee%20ESP8266%20SCH.pdf in this document https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1279.html shows how the signals are connected to physical PINS.

Comment: it doesn't match this. https://wiki.dfrobot.com/SKU_TEL0092_WiFi_Bee-ESP8266_Wirelss_module#target_2  it is a schematics for some diferent board

Comment: I just added a probe to the corner leg of the chip (XPD / GPIO16) and it is indeed connected to PIN9. DFRobot links to this diagram. If it doesn't match, they provide wrong information

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for the information. DFRobot apparently provides different information in different places. I managed to pull high DIO0 and use it to flash a LED. According to your link, this should be NC (impossible)h

Comment: I used PIN 12 (shown in lower corner of the schematic).... I could try 8 instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93805/discussion-between-jens-munk-and-juraj).